# How do you find a maximum character of a vector based on user-defined hierarchy in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

How do you find a maximum character of a vector based on user-defined hierarchy in R?

I have a variable, say `Code` which I would like to impose a hierarchy on so that MSP<1A<1B<1C<2A<2B<2C<...<7C. I want to apply a maximum function on a vector containing these elements. While there's no problem for those characters that are in the form [digit][letter], there is a problem for "MSP". In R, max("2A","MSP") gives "MSP", but I want it to be "2A" instead.

In other words, R will rank it this way 1A<...MSP. This is due to the fact that in R, the hierarchy is "integer < double < character".

**Dataframe:**

```
No<-rep(c(1,2,3),c(4,4,3))
Date<-rep(c("05/09/2013","20/05/2013","23/05/2013","28/05/2013","03/06/2013"),c(2,2,2,2,3))
Time<-rep(c("14:15:00","09:40:00","14:30:00","13:10:00","08:45:00"),c(2,1,3,2,3))
Code<-c("MSP","3A","5B",NA,NA,NA,"7C","3B","MSP","MSP",NA)
df<-data.frame(No,Date,Time,Code,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$Date<-dmy(df$Date)
df$Time<-hms(df$Time)
df

    #     No       Date       Time Code
    # 1   1 2013-09-05 14H 15M 0S  MSP
    # 2   1 2013-09-05 14H 15M 0S   3A
    # 3   1 2013-05-20  9H 40M 0S   5B
    # 4   1 2013-05-20 14H 30M 0S <NA>
    # 5   2 2013-05-23 14H 30M 0S <NA>
    # 6   2 2013-05-23 14H 30M 0S <NA>
    # 7   2 2013-05-28 13H 10M 0S   7C
    # 8   2 2013-05-28 13H 10M 0S   3B
    # 9   3 2013-06-03  8H 45M 0S  MSP
    # 10  3 2013-06-03  8H 45M 0S  MSP
    # 11  3 2013-06-03  8H 45M 0S <NA>
```

**My Code:**
I would like to take the maximum on `Code` (based on the user-defined rank) within each No and Date. So, the rows that share the same No and the same Date will have the same Code. Hence, I grouped it first.

I created a new variable called `CodeAnother` using the `ifelse` function.

1. The condition is such that if there is at least one "MSP"  and not all elements are "MSP"
2. Yes: Take max function by excluding "MSP"
3. No: Take max function the usual way

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   dfnew<-df %>%
      group_by(No,Date) %>%
      mutate(IndicatorMSP=(Code=="MSP" & !is.na(Code))) %>%
      mutate(CodeNo=sum(!is.na(Code))) %>%
      mutate(CodeAnother=ifelse(sum(IndicatorMSP)>=1 & sum(IndicatorMSP)<CodeNo,
                         max(Code[!(Code=="MSP") & !is.na(Code)]),
                         max(Code[!is.na(Code)])))
   ```

I would like to know if there is a nicer way of achieving this using nicer code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

factors are, for once, your friend:

An example where I reorder letters:

```
factoringVariable <- sample(letters)

> factoringVariable
[1] "z" "k" "p" "s" "f" "v" "j" "b" "o" "l" "u" "m" "w" "c" "n" "t" "r" "x" "a" "i" "y" "q" "h" "d" "e" "g"

> sort(factor(letters,levels = factoringVariable))
[1] z k p s f v j b o l u m w c n t r x a i y q h d e g
```

so in your case:

```
factoringVariable <- c('MSP', sort(unlist(outer(1:7,LETTERS[1:3],paste0))))

> factoringVariable
 [1] "MSP" "1A"  "1B"  "1C"  "2A"  "2B"  "2C"  "3A"  "3B"  "3C"  "4A"  "4B"  "4C"  "5A"  "5B"  "5C"  "6A"  "6B"  "6C"  "7A" 
[21] "7B"  "7C"
```

Now that I've set my order:

```
df$Code <- factor(df$Code, levels = factoringVariable)
```

and then you can just use `top_n` function in dplyr (with -1 to get the bottom 1)

```
library(dplyr)
dfnew<-df %>%
  group_by(No,Date) %>%
  top_n(-1,Code)
```

output:

```
> dfnew
Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
Groups: No, Date [4]

     No       Date     Time   Code
  <dbl>      <chr>    <chr> <fctr>
1     1 05/09/2013 14:15:00    MSP
2     1 20/05/2013 09:40:00     5B
3     2 28/05/2013 13:10:00     3B
4     3 03/06/2013 08:45:00    MSP
5     3 03/06/2013 08:45:00    MSP
```

EDIT: I realize now you want to assign all the largest value, in which case, we can't use top_n

instead:

```
library(dplyr)
dfnew<-df %>%
  group_by(No,Date) %>%
  mutate(CodeAll = sort(Code, partial = 1)[1])
```

EDIT 2: you can actually speed it up more (if you need the speed) by using partial sorting, since you're only going to take the first one anyways

Comment: wow this is nice! I never thought of using factors. Actually, I wanted to get the "max" value, so I will just add decreasing=TRUE inside. Anyway, may I know exactly what "partial" does here?

Comment: Sure, you can actually sort a vector much faster if you only need certain values in their correct position. (For an example, try `sort(sample(100), partial = 1:3)`. The first 3 numbers will be in their correct positions, while the  others may or may not be correct. But in this case, you know you're only taking one value from each group, so the partial keeps you from doing unnecessary sorting.